# Dismiss model View Controller

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have scenario where i am presenting view controller using "presentModalViewController " (say FROM MANAGE CONTACTS VIEW CONTROLLER )

```
[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

This takes me to Adrressbook After selecting a adress book I need to push user to a form where he can see the selected user details and save it.

Now it dont know how to push it to form View Controller (that i am using for form). and i dont know how to code for back button is same view controller. Which takes me to back in parent view controller (TO MANAGE CONTACTS VIEW CONTROLLER )

I dont know where to dismiss the controller

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Help Required

Comment: use navigation controller in your application

Answer (score 0):

You will have to dismiss once the user selects the contact, then the delegate must return to the viewcontroller that presented the MANAGE CONTACTS VIEW CONTROLLER with the contact the user selected

Additional explanation on your problem may help